# Make POST request with alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I my swift app . I want to create a request POST with alamofire

The request

```
$ curl \
          -H 'Accept: application/json' \
          -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
          -X POST -d '{ "user": { "email": "user@example.com", "password": "1234" } }' \
          http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

My code

```
let crendetials = ["user": ["email": "bolo@me.com", "password": "PASSWORD"]]
              var postsEndpoint: String = "http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in"
             Alamofire.request(.POST, postsEndpoint, parameters: crendetials, encoding: .JSON)
                  .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
                      if let anError = error
                      {
                          // got an error in getting the data, need to handle it
                          println("error calling POST on /users/sign_in")
                          println(error)
                      }
                      else if let data: AnyObject = data
                      {
                          // handle the results as JSON, without a bunch of nested if loops
                          let post = JSON(data)
                          // to make sure it posted, print the results
                          println(data)
                      }
      }
```

I have got this error

```
request: <NSMutableURLRequest: 0x170208be0> { URL: http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in } || response: nil || object: Optional(<>) || error: Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1004.)" UserInfo=0x1740f6900 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x17405c500 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1004.)"})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're testing with a real iPhone, you should change the host from `localhost` to your Mac's ip address and make sure you iPhone and Mac in the same wireless network.

If you're testing with a simulator, it should work. Maybe you can change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`.

The error is due to wrong url. You can test in Safari in your device to see if it works.

Comment: This is great. I was testing localhost on my iPhone and it would always fail.